# I do not understand this. Why x=1 when enter 5,6$

Tags: c, scanf

The code is:

```
int main(){
   int i=1;
   int j=2;
   char c='a';
   int x=-1;
   x=scanf("%d%d%c", &i, &j,&c);
   printf("%d",x);
}
```

when you enter 5,6$, this output is 1. why?

Comment: The output is 1 because the scanf function is returning 1, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If the input format requires a comma, you must specify that: `"%d,%d%c"`

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf` function returns because it read one field successfully. You asked it to read two integers followed by a character. It read one integer (the 5) but then choked on the comma. So one successful field means a return value of one.